# Defining initial value of ModelChoiceField in def __init__

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm struggling to figure out why I'm not able to populate the jurisdiction field with the value indicated in my def **init** in forms.py. Is there a problem with the way that I'm setting the initial value of this field?

```
class TaxEditForm (forms.ModelForm):  
jurisdiction = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=State.objects.all())    

class Meta:
    model = Tax
    exclude = ('user', 'taxtype',)

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

    self.taxtype = kwargs.pop('taxtype',None)
    self.jurisdiction = kwargs.pop('jurisdiction',None)
    super(TaxEditForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    if self.taxtype == 1:
        self.fields['jurisdiction'].choices = [(t.id, t) for t in State.objects.all()]
        self.fields['jurisdiction'].queryset = State.objects.all()

        self.fields['jurisdiction'].initial = State.objects.get(name=self.jurisdiction)

    elif self.taxtype == 2:
        self.fields['jurisdiction'].choices = [(t.id, t) for t in Country.objects.all()]
        self.fields['jurisdiction'].queryset = Country.objects.all()
        self.fields['jurisdiction'].initial = Country.objects.filter(name=self.jurisdiction)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I had to set the initial value on the form in the view.

```
if taxtype == 2:
    jur = Country.objects.get(name=jurisdiction)
    jurid = jur.id
elif taxtype == 1:
    jur = State.objects.get(name=jurisdiction)
    jurid = jur.id
else:
    jurid = None

form = TaxEditForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=instance, initial={'jurisdiction': jurid}, taxtype=taxtype)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your ModelForm should work if you replace both instances of the following code:

```
self.fields['jurisdiction'].initial =
```

...with...

```
self.initial['jurisdiction'] =
```